# How to write a Signal message using command line?

Tags: bash, command, macos-monterey

I'm trying to write a message on the Signal app only using command lines.

What I think I need to do is : `echo "Hello World" > &fd_of_Signal`

In Linux there is a file like : '/proc/pid_of_app/fd/0' but I didn't find it on MacOs.

So I need to find the FD with the `lsof` command.

I used the command `lsof -c Signal` to get every opened Signal files.

I end up having lots of Signal files opened, with a lot of different FD (in FD column), from 0r to 41.

When I use the `lsof` command for another app (like Spotify), I have the exact same numbers in FD column.

My questions are : How can I differentiate which FD number should I use ? If they are similar for both apps, how can I make my command line understand that I want to use the fd for Signal and not Spotify ? In Linux, there is a file '/proc/pid_of_app/fd/0', is there something similar on MacOs ?

Comment: File descriptors are specific to a particular process. The standard input of another process will not normally be connected to any file descriptor in your shell process. So there's **no** FD you can use to do this.

Comment: You should look into using AppleScript. Most Mac applications can be controlled this way.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for you replies.
I already looked into AppleScript but it does not work in my case.
Everything I looked on internet says the same as you. Too bad for me :/